# for f in *.tiff in Ubuntu gives filenames with the extension

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-14.04

As far as I've understood from other examples, such as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60401/batch-processing-tif-images-converting-tif-to-jpeg) one that converts images within a directory, the following code should store the file name without the extension in `$f`:

```
f in *.tiff
```

When I try to change the extensions using the following code:

```
for f in *.tiff; do mv "$f" "$(basename "$f").jpg"; done
```

I end up with file names such as `diff_14.tiff.jpg`. Is this supposed to happen? How can I fix this?

Note: The conversion script in the link does not work for this reason. I was trying to batch-convert all the `.tiff`s to `.jpg`s, and I narrowed down the problem to the file name extraction. I am changing extensions as a test; I know it would not convert the images.

Comment: Just curious: why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man basename` says "Print NAME with any leading directory components removed."  That's not what you want.  Instead:

```
for f in *.tiff; do mv "$f" "${f%.tiff}.jpg"; done
```

Details: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html